# Pandas mapping syntex

Tags: python, pandas

What is the "pandas" syntex for such mapping?

```
colors = ["red", "black"]
[colors[ind] for ind in [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

with an output of

```
['red', 'black', 'red', 'red', 'black', 'red', 'black']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary created by `enumerate`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]})

colors = ["red", "black"]

df['b'] = df['a'].map(dict(enumerate(colors)))
print (df)
   a      b
0  0    red
1  1  black
2  0    red
3  0    red
4  1  black
5  0    red
6  1  black
```

If all index matching (it means maximal value of column is equal or same like length of list `color`) is possible use numpy broadcasting:

```
colors = ["red", "black"]

df['b'] = np.array(colors)[:, None][df['a'].to_numpy()]
print (df)
   a      b
0  0    red
1  1  black
2  0    red
3  0    red
4  1  black
5  0    red
6  1  black
```